# Performance Profile in python

Tags: python

Hi I want to draw a performance profile directly from python, and the results of implementation are stored in lists, what can I do next? New to python, hope someone can help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Did I misunderstand your link, but actually I mean a figure like this to compare algorithms.  https://www.google.com/search?q=performance+profile+figure&newwindow=1&espv=210&es_sm=122&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=FMw6U8yvL7bfsATj6oL4Ag&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ&biw=1536&bih=756#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=8qrKIgrPtE-HCM%253A%3BInhvEqnoEpz3HM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.mcs.anl.gov%252F~wild%252Ftnoise%252Fappendix_images%252Fstochastic%252Fperf%252FBestofalltestsStochasticsigma10-3.png%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fmcs.anl.gov%252F~wild%252Ftnoise%3B1200%3B900

Answer (score 1):

Python has the built-in profiler.

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html.

Comment: Did I misunderstand your link? But actually I mean a figure like this to compare algorithms. http://www.mcs.anl.gov/~wild/tnoise/appendix_images/stochastic/perf/BestofalltestsStochasticsigma10-3.png